# Site collection custom theme not available for subsites in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Site collection custom theme not available for subsites in Sharepoint 2010 ,do I have to copy the Master theme on the site collection on to each and every subsite ?? or i am missing something ?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you activate the Publishing Features (Both Site Collection, and Site level) you get the option to inherit Themes.

But you'll need to activate publishing for all of the subsites as well.